# Are questions relating to the private party sale of vehicles on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm trying to sell my old car and have some questions about some aspects of it, are those questions on topic?

They obviously are dependent on where I live (both country and state), which mean they're a little localized (though not necessarily *too* localized), but irregardless, they may be off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

My instinct is to look for a mechanical problem / question that needs to be answered.  Example: I am trying to sell this vehicle and I've noticed issue X.  How bad is issue X?  Is that expensive to fix?  Or should I try it myself?

Those abstract examples but they approach something you could answer: how bad / cost = lots of labor?  Part replacement?  Service department labor or sweat equity?  Easy fix / risky fix?

In this example, the sale of the car is relatively incidental but does provide some background and reference points for the answerer.

Comment: That's another point I didn't think about this could give you an idea of ROI, and whether to fix it or sell as is.

Answer (score 2):

[The FAQ states](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

> Questions related to the maintenance and repair of motor vehicles and
>   their accessories, internal combustion engines, even in applications
>   other than automotive so long as the question is related to engine or
>   engine accessories.

It doesn't seem to fit based on that statement, but the community defines the scope of the site, and that statement isn't meant to be all inclusive.

[The FAQ goes on to say](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

I think this is an actual problem you face, but it could easily be an open ended question.

A lot of automotive technicians work for shops that sell cars new and used and many are knowledgeable about the sales/trade-in process. Many automotive technicians and DIYers alike are passionate about cars and end up going through the buy/sell process a lot, and should have knowledge to share on the subject. I don't think it would run them off, or diminish the usefulness of the site by having this type of question.

So with all that being said I would say it depends on the question.

Asking a question about the specific process would be okay. How do I know what my car is worth? Can I sell it to a dealer or at an auction? How do I sell it as a private sale? Should I get a technician to check it out and disclose that information to the seller?

Asking what's the best way to sell my car, wouldn't be a good question.

But that's just my opinion, I could be wrong. Ultimately the community decides buy discussing and voting on meta.

Just a note for new users voting on meta works a little different than the main site you up-vote an answer you agree with, down-vote ones you do not.